# Where is it mentioned that Lord Krishna is 16 kalas but Lord Ram is 12 kalas, when both are same?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, krishna, vaishnavism, rama

It is being popularized by ISKCON I think, that Krishna is purna avatar with 16 kalas but Rama is 12 kalas and is inferior to Krishna, when both are same. Is this even mentioned anywhere by any of the original Vaishnava Saints?

Comment: Rama adhered to Dharma as ideology and duty but unaware of this as an avatar function. But Krishna did the same with full self consciousness and stated the same unequivocally to Arjuna. Do not know how the 12/16 scale rating was devised by ISKON or other pouranic commentator,authority biographer,devotee etc. Please research more quickly on the sources/references and include it here so that up-voters help you more down-voters.

Comment: I do not think it is mentioned anywhere: ISKON just made this up.

Comment: The idea that Krishna has 16 kalas and Rama has 12 kalas is not used by ISKCON. What are those 16 kalas by the way? Can you add them in question if you know?

Comment: Rama adhered to Dharma as ideology and duty but unaware of this as an avatar function. But Krishna did the same with full self consciousness and stated the same unequivocally to Arjuna. Do not know how the 12/16 scale rating was devised by ISKON or other pouranic commentator,authority biographer,devotee etc.

Please research early on the sources/references and include it here with voting.